# How to split the Cora dataset to train a GCN model only on training part?

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, neural-network, pytorch

I am training a GCN (Graph Convolutional Network) on Cora dataset.

The Cora dataset has the following attributes:

```
Number of graphs: 1
Number of features: 1433
Number of classes: 7
Number of nodes: 2708
Number of edges: 10556
Number of training nodes: 140
Training node label rate: 0.05
Is undirected: True

Data(edge_index=[2, 10556], test_mask=[2708], train_mask=[2708], val_mask=[2708], x=[2708, 1433], y=[2708])
```

Since my code is very long, I only put the relevent parts of my code here. Firstly, I split the Cora dataset as follows:

```
def to_mask(index, size):
    mask = torch.zeros(size, dtype=torch.bool)
    mask[index] = 1
    return mask

def cora_splits(data, num_classes):
    indices = []

    for i in range(num_classes):
        # returns all indices of the elements = i from data.y tensor
        index = (data.y == i).nonzero().view(-1)

        # returns a random permutation of integers from 0 to index.size(0).
        index = index[torch.randperm(index.size(0))]

        # indices is a list of tensors and it has a length of 7
        indices.append(index)

    # select 20 nodes from each class for training
    train_index = torch.cat([i[:20] for i in indices], dim=0)

    rest_index = torch.cat([i[20:] for i in indices], dim=0)
    rest_index = rest_index[torch.randperm(len(rest_index))]

    data.train_mask = to_mask(train_index, size=data.num_nodes)
    data.val_mask = to_mask(rest_index[:500], size=data.num_nodes)
    data.test_mask = to_mask(rest_index[500:], size=data.num_nodes)

    return data
```

The `train` is as follows (taken from [here](https://github.com/tkipf/pygcn/blob/master/pygcn/train.py) with few modifications):

```
def train(model, optimizer, data, epoch):
    t = time.time()
    model.train()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = model(data)
    loss_train = F.nll_loss(output[data.train_mask], data.y[data.train_mask])
    acc_train = accuracy(output[data.train_mask], data.y[data.train_mask])
    loss_train.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    loss_val = F.nll_loss(output[data.val_mask], data.y[data.val_mask])
    acc_val = accuracy(output[data.val_mask], data.y[data.val_mask])

def accuracy(output, labels):
    preds = output.max(1)[1].type_as(labels)
    correct = preds.eq(labels).double()
    correct = correct.sum()
    return correct / len(labels)
```

When I ran my code with 200 epochs in 10 runs I gained:

```
tensor([0.7690, 0.8030, 0.8530, 0.8760, 0.8600, 0.8550, 0.8850, 0.8580, 0.8940, 0.8830])

Val Loss: 0.5974, Test Accuracy: 0.854 ± 0.039
```

where each value in the tensor belongs to the model accurracy of each run and the mean accuracy of all those 10 runs is 0.854 with std ± 0.039.

As it can be observed, the accuracy from the first run to the 10th one is increasing substantially. Therefore, I think the model is overfitting. One reason of overfitting is that in the code, the test data has been seen by the model in the training time since in the `train` function, there is a line `output = model(data)` so the model is trained over the whole data. What I intend to do is to train my model only on a part of the data (something similar to `data[data.train_mask]`) but the problem is I cannot pass `data[data.train_mask]`, due to the `forward` function of the `GCN` model (from [this repository](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_geometric/blob/master/benchmark/kernel/gcn.py)):

```
def forward(self, data):
        x, edge_index = data.x, data.edge_index
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x, edge_index))
        for conv in self.convs:
            x = F.relu(conv(x, edge_index))
        x = F.relu(self.lin1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, p=0.5, training=self.training)
        x = self.lin2(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=-1)
```

If I pass `data[data.train_mask]` to the GCN model, then in the above `forward` function in line `x, edge_index = data.x, data.edge_index`, `x` and `edge_index` cannot be retrieved from `data[data.train_mask]`. Therefore, I need to find a way to split the Cora dataset in a way that I can pass a specefic part of it with the nodes, edge-index and other attributes to the model. My question is how to do it?

Also, any suggestion about k-fold cross validation is much appreciated.

Comment: Note that vanilla GCN deals with *transductive* learning, where the test data is seen (without knowing the labels) during training. What you are saying is *inductive* learning, and you probably need to change more of the code (like, use minibatches) to make it performs reasonably well.  See [GraphSage](http://snap.stanford.edu/graphsage/) for an example.

Comment: @hkchengrex Thank you. I checked the link you provided with the corresponding codes (GitHub repository) and the `citation_eval.py` [here](https://github.com/williamleif/GraphSAGE/blob/master/eval_scripts/citation_eval.py). The datasets they use are "Protein-Protein Interactions" and "Reddit", which have different structures than the Cora dataset. The challenge with the Cora dataset is that it only contains one graph, and creating minibatches is not straightforward.

Comment: Yeah. By its nature, single-graph Cora is much more suited in a transductive setting. You probably need to think about what do you actually want to achieve, i.e. to change the dataset or to change the setting.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are a little confused by the nature of [transductive learning](https://towardsdatascience.com/inductive-vs-transductive-learning-e608e786f7d) and the question you asked doesn't actually address the problem you are facing.

> As it can be observed, the accuracy from the first run to the 10th one
> is increasing substantially. Therefore, I think the model is
> overfitting.

Not necessarily, increasing test accuracy could be a normal behavior when your model is **learning** from the training samples. The **learning** can last for several dozens of epochs due to the complexity and non-convexity of loss function. The best signal to tell overfit is when your training accuracy increase but test accuracy decreases significantly.

> One reason of overfitting is that in the code, the test data has been
> seen by the model in the training time since in the train function,
> there is a line output = model(data) so the model is trained over the
> whole data.

The model indeed has seen the entire graph(adjacency matrix) in the training, but it only sees the labels of nodes in the training set and knows nothing about the labels of nodes in the test set. This is exactly what **transductive learning** does.

In the end, if you are 100% sure you want to avoid the paradigm of **transductive learning**, then you might need to write your own split algorithm to achieve that. But I would like to remind that in the real-world use case, transduction is perfectly suitable. An example is to predict the potential links between social network users, where we have the whole network structure as input and want to simply run edge prediction--> transduction.  Thus it doesn't make a lot of sense to avoid it.

---

Depending on your task, you could take a look of how Stellargraph's `EdgeSplitter` class([docs](https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#stellargraph.data.EdgeSplitter)) and scikit-learn’s `train_test_split` function ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#sklearn-model-selection-train-test-split)) achive the split.

### Node classification

If your task is a node classification task, this [Node classification with Graph Convolutional Network (GCN)](https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/stable/demos/node-classification/gcn-node-classification.html#Splitting-the-data) is a good example of how to load data and do train-test-split. It took Cora dataset as an example. The most important steps are the following:

```
dataset = sg.datasets.Cora()
display(HTML(dataset.description))
G, node_subjects = dataset.load()

train_subjects, test_subjects = model_selection.train_test_split(
    node_subjects, train_size=140, test_size=None, stratify=node_subjects
)
val_subjects, test_subjects = model_selection.train_test_split(
    test_subjects, train_size=500, test_size=None, stratify=test_subjects
)

train_gen = generator.flow(train_subjects.index, train_targets)
val_gen = generator.flow(val_subjects.index, val_targets)
test_gen = generator.flow(test_subjects.index, test_targets)
```

Basically, it's the same as train-test-split with a normal classification task, except what we split here is nodes.

### Edge classification

If your task is edge classification, you could have a look at this [Link prediction example: GCN on the Cora citation dataset](https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.0rc1/demos/link-prediction/gcn/cora-gcn-links-example.html#Link-prediction-example:-GCN-on-the-Cora-citation-dataset). The most relevant code for train-test-split is

```
# Define an edge splitter on the original graph G:
edge_splitter_test = EdgeSplitter(G)

# Randomly sample a fraction p=0.1 of all positive links, and same number of negative links, from G, and obtain the
# reduced graph G_test with the sampled links removed:
G_test, edge_ids_test, edge_labels_test = edge_splitter_test.train_test_split(
    p=0.1, method="global", keep_connected=True
)

# Define an edge splitter on the reduced graph G_test:
edge_splitter_train = EdgeSplitter(G_test)

# Randomly sample a fraction p=0.1 of all positive links, and same number of negative links, from G_test, and obtain the
# reduced graph G_train with the sampled links removed:
G_train, edge_ids_train, edge_labels_train = edge_splitter_train.train_test_split(
    p=0.1, method="global", keep_connected=True
)

# For training we create a generator on the G_train graph, and make an 
# iterator over the training links using the generator’s flow() method:

train_gen = FullBatchLinkGenerator(G_train, method="gcn")
train_flow = train_gen.flow(edge_ids_train, edge_labels_train)
test_gen = FullBatchLinkGenerator(G_test, method="gcn")
test_flow = train_gen.flow(edge_ids_test, edge_labels_test)
```

Here the splitting algorithm behind `EdgeSplitter` class([docs](https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#stellargraph.data.EdgeSplitter))  is more complex, it needs to maintain the graph structure while doing the split, such as keeping the graph connectivity for example. For more details, cf source code for [EdgeSplitter](https://github.com/stellargraph/stellargraph/blob/develop/stellargraph/data/edge_splitter.py#L32)